# Removing arrays/indexes in a jagged array using foreach C#

Tags: c#, arrays

In the listed example I try to add the indexes to a List and delete them from the Array. How do I go about doing this?

Moreover I would also like to be able to delete entire Arrays in the jagged array can I accomplish this in a similar way?

I already tried casting the Array to a list and removing the elements but when I exit the `foreach` loop they still get added to the Snail List (`snail.Add(list.Last());`)

All help is appreciated!

```
 public static int[] Snail(int[][] array)
{
    List<int> snail = new List<int>();
    foreach (int[] list in array)
    {
        if (list == array.First())
        {
            foreach (int i in list)
            {
                snail.Add(i);
                int numToRemove = i;
                list = list.Where(val => val != numToRemove).ToArray(); // Not possible
            }
            snail.Add(list.Last());
            list.ToList().Remove(list.Last());
                          
        }
}
```

Comment: It isn't really a good idea to change a list/array if you are using that list/array to iterate over in a `foreach`. Can you also add an example with input and the expected output? It is very unclear from the question.

Comment: You cannot *delete* items from an array, but you can *replace* them, possibly using null, or recreate the entire array without the value.  But if you need to replace values you need to use a regular for loop. More importantly, *what are you actually trying to do*? It seem fairly likely that you have selected a poor data structure for whatever your task is.

Comment: @JonasH : What the OP did is perfectly legal except OP is changing a loop iterator inside the loop which is not allowed.

Comment: @jdweng Did I claim otherwise? But being legal does not necessarily make it a good idea. To me, this smells like a XY-problem, i.e. the attempted solution is overly complicated due to the data structure selection, and there is likely easier and better solutions, but it is difficult to suggest one without understanding the context of the problem.